# JSP member field used in different files

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, fortify

I have a JSP file which has "title" as member field. This member field is being used across 5 different JSP files. Each page modifying the member to display it's individual contents.

Main JSP file (shared memeber field) :

private String  titlePage = "";

Remaining 5 pages:

```
<% titlePage = "title 1"; %>
<% titlePage = "title 2"; %>
```

I am using Fortify to scan it. Which gives me the following error:
he class MainTitlePage.jsp is a singleton, so the member field titlePage is shared between users. The result is that one user could see another user's data.Servlet member fields might allow one user to see another user's data.

Why is my JSP page singleton? Is it related to scope? and what is the solution for it.

Comment: Just don't declare it as member field?

Comment: The file is being shared (using include tag) across the other JSPs, there are few other things apart from member field which are being shared.
shld I like include the complete page directly instead of using include tags ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using scriptlets!